# Standard way to implement mobile app web services

Tags: php, arrays, web-services, mobile-application

I am a PHP developer and need to implement web services for mobile application developers to share data such as posts, likes, etc.

What is the best way to implement such web services? Is there a standard for stuff like this?

Currently I do output JSON with messages, contents and so on.

My main problem with app developers is about error messages. I suggest to return an array with error codes and messages to show:

```
$result = array(
    'status' => false, // because registration failed
                       // if registration succeed then would be true
    'errors' => array(
        array(
            'code' => '1',
            'message' => 'Password is not strong enough!',
        ),
        array(
            'code' => '2',
            'message' => 'Password and password confirmation do not match!',
        ),
        array(
            'code' => '3',
            'message' => 'This email address has been used!',
        ),
    ),
);
```

But they suggest to return all error messages as an string and they would only use the status parameter and if it was false then will show message, something like this:

```
$result = array(
    'status' => false,
    'message' => 'Password is not strong enough!' . PHP_EOL .
                 'Password and password confirmation do not match!' . PHP_EOL .
                 'This email address has been used!',
);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest to take a look [here](https://www.toptal.com/php/building-rest-api-for-legacy-php-projects) and [here](http://gtjourney.gatech.edu/live/gt-devhub/documentation/restful-api-structure).

Answer (score 2):

[Dozens of web-services protocols exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_service_protocols), the most famous one being (IMO) SOAP. [Some of them](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.webservice.php) are natively supported by PHP, most of them have open-source implementations available, all of them might be an overkill for simple requirements.

For a basic error handling mechanism, a simple [5xx HTTP status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) may suffice:

```
<?php

define('HTTP_CUSTOM_ERROR_CODE', 599);
define('HTTP_CUSTOM_ERROR_REASON', 'Something wrong is going on');

if( somethingWrong() ) {

    header(
        sprintf('%s %s %s',
            $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'],
            HTTP_CUSTOM_ERROR_CODE,
            HTTP_CUSTOM_ERROR_REASON
        ),
        true,
        HTTP_CUSTOM_ERROR_CODE
    ); // sends HTTP header "HTTP/1.1 599 Something wrong is going on"

    echo $errorMessage; // or echo json_encode( $structuredErrorData );
    die();

} else {

    echo json_encode( $response );

}
```

As per the HTTP protocol specifications, any HTTP client is supposed to handle this error condition. Refer to your platform's manual for more information, or tell us more about your target mobile platform.

Comment: Thank you RandomSeed. I read the resources you introduced. They opened my mind about web services and i think your answer worth 50 bounty (and even more).

Answer (score 1):

Use a framework. Don't roll your own web service layer. If you know you need to
roll your own then you have enough experience to answer this question :)

Framework choice and Service protocol to use are the next obvious questions.

**Protocol**... don't use SOAP unless forced to use it, use REST/RPC. Both REST and RPC are easier to implement and most frameworks you'll find can do both out of the box.

**Framework**... pick the simplest you can to avoid a massive learning curve ie.

Choice of what technology to use and why is really up to you. You can find a list of popular frameworks here

http://www.sitepoint.com/best-php-framework-2015-sitepoint-survey-results/

Note, preferences in frameworks are quite often subjective ie people (including me) will suggest you use what they're familiar with. If you had time I'd suggest you implement a basic service in several frameworks to see which one you prefer working with ie you get to read their docs and install it in your container ie Apache/Nginx etc, this is quite often a quick way to find out you hate a particular framework.

I personally consider any framework that requires a database to install it and see a web page as complex. Something like Drupal can be a shock, it has steep learning curve because it has everything, most of which you won't need if you're just building services.

Yii2 is quite simple and it has docs on implmenting REST...

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html

Laravel might also be a good choice...

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2

The docs are pretty good in both these projects. They're easy to use, and you can install them using composer...

Remember what I said about personal preferences. I've used Yii and have had no
problems with it. You might hate it with a passion. Have a look here for a very different opinion on Yii, some people hate it...

http://laravel.io/forum/04-29-2015-suggestions-for-technology-stack-choice-laravel-5-vs-yii-2

This guy wrote a book on Yii and now he prefers Laravel.

https://yii2framework.wordpress.com/tag/yii-2-0-vs-laravel/

Comment: Thank you harry. Yes, I am working with frameworks. I have worked with CodeIgniter and Laravel, and the project that i am working on, has been built on CakePHP. There were developers before me working on this project and they have implemented web-services too. But I really do not want to implement web-services like old ones. Their structure is not good at all. I wanted to implement new Web-Services as good as possible and I wanted to know what is the best way. I had some idea that mentioned in question's body. Thanks.

Comment: Your question does not make sense. What they appear to be asking for is a response in JSON and the statue will tell them if it's an error or not. If using REST then this `'status' => false,` is not a good way to indicate an error. The HTTP status should be used ie HTTP 404 == not found, HTTP 403 == Forbidden etc.

Comment: Thank you. That was convincing.